# prependTo adds 2 list items instead of 1

Tags: jquery, carousel, appendto

I have a carrousel with a .pre and .next button. A click on .pre moves the li:last to li:first, and the other way around.

This works fine if there is only one carrousel, when i add 2 carrousels with a different ID a click on .pre adds 2 li's to the front instead of 1. Why is that?

```
        <div class="carrousel" id="featuredAppartments">

            <a href="" class="move pre">Previous</a> <a href="" class="move next ">Next</a>

            <div class="list">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=""><div class="imgWrap"><img src="assets/img/thumb2.png" alt=""><i class="ico ribbonLowered">Featured</i></div> <p><strong>Amsterdam</strong> Grachtengordel <br> € 2500,00</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><div class="imgWrap"><img src="assets/img/thumb2.png" alt=""></div> <p><strong>Amsterdam</strong> Grachtengordel <br> € 2500,00</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><div class="imgWrap"><img src="assets/img/thumb2.png" alt=""></div> <p><strong>Amsterdam</strong> Grachtengordel <br> € 2500,00</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><div class="imgWrap"><img src="assets/img/thumb2.png" alt=""><i class="ico ribbonRented">Featured</i></div> <p><strong>Amsterdam</strong> Grachtengordel <br> € 2500,00</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><div class="imgWrap"><img src="assets/img/thumb2.png" alt=""><i class="ico ribbonNew">Featured</i></div> <p><strong>Amsterdam</strong> Grachtengordel <br> € 2500,00</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><div class="imgWrap"><img src="assets/img/thumb2.png" alt=""><i class="ico ribbonNew">Featured</i></div> <p><strong>Amsterdam</strong> Grachtengordel <br> € 2500,00</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><div class="imgWrap"><img src="assets/img/thumb2.png" alt=""><i class="ico ribbonNew">Featured</i></div> <p><strong>Amsterdam</strong> Grachtengordel <br> € 2500,00</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><div class="imgWrap"><img src="assets/img/thumb2.png" alt=""><i class="ico ribbonNew">Featured</i></div> <p><strong>Amsterdam</strong> Grachtengordel <br> € 2500,00</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><div class="imgWrap"><img src="assets/img/thumb2.png" alt=""><i class="ico ribbonNew">Featured</i></div> <p><strong>Amsterdam</strong> Grachtengordel <br> € 2500,00</p></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <script>

                $(document).ready(function() {

                    var t = $('#featuredAppartments ul');

                    $('.next').click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();t.find('li:first').appendTo(t);});
                    $('.pre').click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();t.find('li:last').prependTo(t);});

                });

            </script>

        </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed the script to this, but the second carousel still adds 2 li's instead of just 1.

```
            <script>

                $(document).ready(function() {

                    var t = $('#featuredAppartments ul');

                    $('#featuredAppartments .next').click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();t.find('li:first').appendTo(t);});
                    $('#featuredAppartments .pre').click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();t.find('li:last').prependTo(t);});

                });

            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question lies in your code for the second carousel which you didn't provide..
I just made a jsfiddle very quickly from your code. It's not having any good markup so I would recommend to rewrite it. http://jsfiddle.net/PQQEe/

Basically you probably forgot to change some variables appropriately.. like your t.find..

Lets say the 2nd carrousel has the id "more". So your JS would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#featuredAppartments ul');

    $('#featuredAppartments .next').click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();t.find('li:first').appendTo(t);});
    $('#featuredAppartments .pre').click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();t.find('li:last').prependTo(t);});

    var d = $('#more ul');

    $('#more .next').click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();d.find('li:first').appendTo(d);});
    $('#more .pre').click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();d.find('li:last').prependTo(d);});

});
```

You now select the buttons by the carousel ID and you also only access the list within each carousel. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code says `$('.pre')`, which will attach the click handler to *every* element with the `pre` class set. So when the user clicks once, both carousels respond, and each adds its own li.

You'll want to make your selector more specific, or your handler...

Comment: Does that matter? Since any click on any .pre is fine since it selects the var t and this is a specific selector: t.find('li:first').appendTo(t)

Comment: Ok, i get it.. but why is the second carousel adding 2 items instead of just 1?